# ImageMagick: how to minimally crop an image to a fixed aspect ratio regardless of the image's dimensions?

Tags: image, terminal, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

ImageMagick can minimally crop images from the center of an image at a certain aspect ratio.

For example, an image named "input-image.jpg" which is 3000px x 2000px can be minimally cropped, from the center of the image and at a 16:9 aspect ratio, by using the following command.

```
convert input-image.jpg -gravity center -crop 16:9 output-image.jpg
```

However, if the image has a larger height than width, that same `convert` command above will crop the image at the inverse aspect ratio of 9:16. For example, if the dimensions of the image is 2000px x 3000px instead of 3000px x 2000px, ImageMagick will crop the image at a 9:16 aspect ratio even-though a 16:9 aspect ratio is called for in the `convert` command

In ImageMagick, how do you crop an image, at the center of the image and at a certain aspect ratio, regardless of the input image's height and width?

Comment: Perhaps pad your image to the desired aspect ratio before you crop it.

Comment: Test the image dimensions first. Figure out if it is portrait or landscape, then write your crop command as either 16:9 or 9:16.  Or rotate your image 90 degrees if portrait so landscape and then use 16:9, then rotate the crop back by -90 deg